# physical or geometrical meaning of orthogonality of function

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

basically I'm not a mathematician. I have three doubts in relating discrete space and continuous space.

We know that if two vectors are orthogonal then we can say, their dot product is zero 
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=0$$
The physical meaning of this is $\vec{a}$ has no projection in $\vec{b}$. In other words, lets assume there are two poles defined by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, if we pass a light ray perpendicular to a pole  $\vec{a}$ that will produce no shadow in pole defined by $\vec{b}$ and vice-versa.

If we convert this vector space into functional space this will become [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)

$\langle a,b\rangle =\int a(x)*b(x) dx $

**Question 1**

Please explain the physical meaning of orthogonal functions. We know physical meaning of integration is area or equivalent term is discrete summation ($\Sigma$). Then what is geometric or physical meaning of product of two functions ?

**Question 2:**

We know $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are orthogonal in the interval $0$ to $2\pi$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin (x) \cos (x) dx =0$$

Lets assume we are discretizing the function to 3 equal intervals from $0$ to $2\pi$

$\sin(x) =[ 0, 0, 0]$

$\cos(x) =[1, -1, 1]$

If we take dot product we will get zero, so this is working fine.

Formula to calculate length of the vector $\vec{a}$ is $\langle a,a\rangle$ 
In functional space this will become $\int a(x) * a(x) dx$

Lets say our function is  $a(x) =\sin (x)$, we want to find length in discrete space in the interval $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\int^{\pi/2}_0 \sin(x) \sin(x) dx =0.7854 $

I have divided the interval $(x)$ into $10001$ parts and calculated dot product then the value is

$\sum_0^{n=11} \sin(x) \sin(x)   =5.0005*10^3 $, multiplying this with grid size ($\delta x$ =$\pi/2*10$) we get $0.7855$

Both the answer is more or less same.
Then we can say

$$\int f(x) f(x) dx  = \delta x \sum f_i f_i = \delta x \langle f_i f_i\rangle$$

I think this is the relation between discrete space and continuous functional space.  Am I right?

In the previous relation of Wikipedia  ($\langle a,b\rangle =\int a(x)*b(x) dx $)

$\delta x$ is missing!

**Question 3:**

In the above example I have used uniform grid, in case If I used non-uniform grid that relation is not valid, is there is any simple mathematical relation that relate discrete space and continuous space for non-uniform grid.